# Are my fragment badly communicating?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So at work we have an activity with 4 fragments, in a MVVM architecture with databinding.

```
InfoActivity
    ScreenOneFragment
    ScreenTwoFragment
    ScreenTreeFragment
    ScreenFourFragment
```

Each fragment as its own view model that can be accessed throught the ViewModelProvider

```
ScreenOneVM
ScreenTwoVM
ScreenTreeVM
ScreenFourVM
```

The `ViewModelProvider` is some kind of singleton manager, once someone request a VM this VM is built and then it will always be that instance that will be given to everyone. (untill infoActivity dies)

**First problem :**

When something specific change in screen 3 I want to update a part of screen 4

in the `ScreenFourFragment` in the `OnActivityCreated` method the `ScreenTreeVm` is requested from the `ViewModelProvider`.
Once the `screenTreeVm` is retrieved the fragment observe a property of this VM

`screenTreeVm.getLastSelectedUserChoice().observe(this, this::updateLeftDrawer);`

and this getter is like this, to ensure that everyone use the same instance :

```
public MutableLiveData<UserChoice> getLastSelectedUserChoice() {
        if (null == this.lastUserChoice) {
            this.lastUserChoice = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }
        return this.lastUserChoice;
    }
```

As such, each time the user change the value of a spinner in the 3rd screen, the 4th screen view model is updated.

**Second problem :**

there is a `MutableLiveData<Boolean> isUpdateRequired` in the `ScreenFourVM` and sometime the other Fragments will set a value inside in order to trigger an update method in the `screenFour`.

Once again in the `OnActivityCreated` method of the `ScreenFourFagment` an observer is put on this property (the property is in the `ScreenFourVm`)

(on observer is always trigered when a value is set, even if this value is the same as before)

I don't really like that because this is not really "is an update required"

if `ScreenOneFragment` set it to true then it triggers the method
if a little bit after `ScreenTwoFragment` set it to true (while it was already true) it triggers the method

But the content of isUpdateRequired is always true.

---

this seems to me to be some spaghetti mess, sometimes a fragment will set a value in screenFourvm triggering a change, sometimes screenFourVm will trigger a change because it's observing properties in other VMs.

How would you tackle this problem?

Thanks.